# python insert block of set.result to textboxes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the below code. My problem is that i want to insert the 'for' results into textboxes. If i run the code, my textboxes  are filled with the same value (naturally, because textvariable=name_project in the five labels, so after the fetchall & for, the boxes take the same value). I tried to set textvariable=name_project.set(results[0][0]) but there is an indexing issue and ihave lost....

```
#=============2nd_query======================#
    curs1.execute("select name_project,description, count(*) from customer_des where company_name_d='%s' group by name_project, description"%e2.get())
    results=curs1.fetchall()
    r_count=curs.rowcount

    if r_count==0:
     print("no rows")
    else:
     for i in range (0, r_count):
#=============check rowcount in order to fill the appropriate textboxes======================#                 
      if i in range (0,1):
       name_project=(results[0][0])
       description=(results[0][1])
       fname_project1.set(name_project) #new variable insertion
       fdescription1.set(description) #new variable insertion
      if i in range (0,2):
        name_project=(results[0][0])
        description=(results[0][1])
        fname_project1.set(name_project)
        fdescription1.set(description)
        name_project=(results[1][0])
        description=(results[1][1])
        fname_project2.set(name_project)
        fdescription2.set(description)
      if i in range (0,3):
        name_project=(results[0][0])
        description=(results[0][1])
        fname_project1.set(name_project)
        fdescription1.set(description)
        name_project=(results[1][0])
        description=(results[1][1])
        fname_project2.set(name_project)
        fdescription2.set(description)              
        name_project=(results[2][0])
        description=(results[2][1])
        fname_project3.set(name_project)
        fdescription3.set(description)
```

Comment: This is an awful lot of code... I'd recommend doing some basic troubleshooting. Get rid of/simplify small blocks of code one at a time until the problem goes away, then examine the last change you made.

Comment: Please reduce this down to a [mcve]. You've posted way more code than is necessary to illustrate your problem.

Comment: I solved my problem with the insertion of new variables, but now i have another. Although the GUI is functional, i noticed in the IDLE that when the rowcount equals the max value (in the above example=3) there is no error message, but when it is <3, although the values are inserted in the textboxes, there is  the message: File "C:\...\...\Desktop\python\list_2_2.py", line 38, in search name_project=(results[1][0]) IndexError: list index out of range